# Event listener function called after it was removed in IE11

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been building component listening to clicks on the whole document and stumbled upon IE11 issue.

I wrote a couple of simple components to reproduce this issue.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      show: false
    }
  }

  render() {
    return ( 
      <div>
        <button 
          onClick={() => this.setState({
              show: !this.state.show
          })}
        >
          Toggle
        </button>
        
        <div>
          {this.state.show && (
            <Component />
          )} 
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Component extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('listener added')
    document.addEventListener('click', this.handleClick)
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    console.log('listener removed')
    document.removeEventListener('click', this.handleClick)
  }

  handleClick() {
    console.log('clicked!');
    const node = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);
  }

  render() {
    return <div>Component</div>
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <App /> ,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

So, the `Component` component adds click listener to document, and `App` component takes care of mounting and unmounting `Component`.

Everything works perfect in Chrome and Firefox, when `Component` is mounted event listener is applied and when it is unmounted listener is removed.

In IE11 however, when listener is removed, handler function is still called after and error is thrown because it tries to `findDOMNode` of unmounted component. This may not be a breaking issue, but it still bugs me and I would like to know if there is any workaround.

Also, note - stopping propagation via `event.stopPropagation` is not an option because in my app `Component` can be unmounted with many ways, button click is just an example

[JSFiddle reproducing the issue](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/68778/)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug in IE11. A few options:

1.

Using `window.addEventListener/window.removeEventListener` vs. `document.addEventListener/document.removeEventListener` should work.

2.

I've seen other solutions wrap the handler with `isMounted`:

```
if (this.isMounted) {
    const node = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);
}
```

But `isMounted` is deprecated and gives a warning. [It is considered an antipattern](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html).

3.

A current *hack* would be to create your own `isMounted`. Something like:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.mounted = true;
    document.addEventListener('click', this.handleClick)
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    this.mounted = false;
    document.removeEventListener('click', this.handleClick)
}

handleClick() {
    if (this.mounted) {
        const node = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);
    }
}
```

But this only gets around the `isMounted` console warning.